# Difference between CE, CB and CC transistor configurations

Tags: transistors, bjt, common-emitter, common-collector, common-base

In the different configurations of transistors, namely Common Base (CB), Common Emitter (CE) and Common Collector (CC), I am asked about the basic difference.

So can I say that the basic difference is that in each configuration the Base, Emitter and Collector are grounded respectively? That is in CB the base is grounded, in CE the Emitter is grounded and in CC the Collector is grounded?

Kindly clarify this for me.

Comment: You'd need a bit more context. If the asker is looking for a short one-line answer in a test where the question is only worth 1 point, then yes that's probably the correct answer. But if they expect more than that then you're probably expected to describe the differences in how they work and/or compare features like voltage/current gain and input/output impedance.

Comment: *In the different combinations of transistors* You mean different transistor **configurations**. The transistor remains the same, the way how it is used changes. As an educational exercise, write down for all 3 configurations what their properties are as in: voltage transfer, current transfer, input impedance, output impedance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am sorry, what I meant was configuration.

Comment: @AhmadQayyum I did recently offer some thoughts on [CB, CC, and CE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/566474/38098) arrangements. They may be helpful to read, if you are at a point where they may find purchase with you.

Answer (score 4):

> That is in CB the base is grounded, in Ce the Emitter is grounded and in CC the Collector is grounded?

Not quite. It could be that the named terminal is grounded. But more precisely, it means that named terminal is not exclusively part of the input nor exclusively part of the output.

To make this more concrete, here is an example.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgO3Fk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a common emitter configuration. The emitter is *not* grounded, but it does not clearly belong exclusively to the input, nor exclusively to the output.

Comment: this is a more specified version. What I am asking is answer in one-line or the one that can be asked in an interview.