# Load current of a transistor (BJT)

Tags: transistors, bjt

What does 'load current of a transistor (BJT)' mean?

Comment: The bias voltage Vbe is externally set by the voltage divider. What do you mean with "...change the Vbe value of Bjt in LTspice" ?

Comment: Please do not make large edits that invalidate existing answers -- the content of your edit however can be pasted into a new question.

Comment: @TimWilliams true but it would probably take an admin to migrate the bounty as well. I'll flag the issue.

Comment: @tobalt - Even mods cannot move a bounty to a different question nor create a new question under the username of someone else. || The major edit to the question, which invalidates the existing answer, should not have been done by the OP, so I will rollback the question to its earlier state. That does mean the bounty is effectively useless as it won't apply to the true question. Therefore I will remove the bounty.

Comment: Star Lord (you will get this notification even without an `@`) - Please do not edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answer(s). I know why you did it, but that is not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the load (for example, a resistor, loadspeaker or the input of a next stage) is grounded, it is normally connected in parallel to the transistor. The common current through the collector resistor splits into two parts - a current that flows through the load (load current) and current flowing through the transistor. Shortly, the load current is a property of the load and not of the transistor.

If the load is floating (e.g., the collector resistor), the same current flows through the transistor and the load.

See also [my story](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/661568/61398) related to your question.

Comment: Where is it connected at what terminals (C, B, E)?

Comment: @Star Lord, In the first (grounded load) configuration, the load is connected between the collector and emitter; in the second (floating load) configuration, the load is connected between the collector and Vcc. Please, see [my related story about the transistor amplifier stage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/661568/61398). I would write such a story especially for you, but I'm coming home from vacation right now and I'm worried about time.